# C#: Folder not showing in current namespace

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I am creating a small application so that I can learn C#. I am using Visual Studio Code and .Net Core 3.

When I started the project, the namespace was given as `SireEdu`. In the Solution explorer, I created a coupe of folders in which I placed some User Controls.

[The tree where the folders are located](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDweq.png)

When referencing the content of those folders, I had no problem at all as you can see below here:

[The folders appear in the namespace SireEdu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoBkk.png)

I decided to add another folder in the same location called Security and try the same thing, but this time the folder does not appear in the namespace and it is throwing me an error:`The Type or namespace 'Security' does not exist in the namespace 'SireEdu.Usercontrols'`

[The new folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7637R.png)

I don't understand this error since I am doing exactly the same thing as I did before.

This might look trivial but for me as beginner, I am having a hard time finding a solution.

Comment: Please replace the screenshots with a tree-like structure. It's not possible to know right now the location of each folder or where you are getting the error. It'll be better if you can also add the code (even if it's a small sample, we don't need the entire classes)

Comment: The folders themselves don't supply any namespace.  When you add a class under a folder, it'll build the namespace from the folder structure by default, but can be changed.  What does your class look like that's in the `Security` folder?

Comment: @Janesopolis I found the issue thanks to your comment. I created the new classes in the new folder and they were assigned another namespace, which caused the error. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Namespaces are not defined by the folder structure of your project.

They are defined by your namespace declarations.

```
namespace SampleNamespace
{
    class SampleClass
    {
        public void SampleMethod()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(
              "SampleMethod inside SampleNamespace");
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, you'll find you can access the SampleNamespace even if the file is not inside a folder called SampleNamespace.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue, but it happened because I didn't declare the class as public.

```
public class CustomerModel  
{

}
```